# Kahler metric and $(1,1)$- forms

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

I am following [this](http://www.hri.res.in/~sen/compact4.pdf) set of lecture notes. On page 3, the author is considering a metric on a complex Kahler manifold of dimension $n$, which is denoted by $g_{\alpha, \bar{\beta}} = \partial_{\alpha}\partial_{\bar{\beta}} K(\vec{z}, \vec{\bar{z}})$. Immediately afterwards, the author writes down a (1,1)-form given by $J = g_{\alpha, \bar{\beta}} dz^{\alpha} \wedge d\bar{z}^{\bar{\beta}}$, which he shows is a $(1,1)$ form belonging to $H^{(1,1)}$ cohomology class, and subsequently defines a Kahler class.

My question is this, the metric is symmetric in its indices, so then how can it be used to construct a (1,1)-form, which is antisymmetric in its indices? What am I missing here?  Is the antisymmetrization independently in the $z$'s and the $\bar{z}$'s and hence this is alright?

Comment: Is the author missing a $\wedge$ sign? Some authors just don't bother with them...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Hi, the author wasn't missing it but I made a typo, thanks for that. My question revolves around the wedge product only, the metric is symmetric in its indices, so in that case how are we using it in a wedge product?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is the antisymmetrization independently in the $z$'s and the $\bar{z}$'s and hence this is alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that your $J$ is a *product* of the symmetric metric by the antisymmetric (1,1)-forms $dz^\alpha\wedge d\bar{z}^\beta$. A symmetric thing times an antisymmetric thing is antisymmetric. So, for example, 
\begin{align*}
J(X,Y)=\left(g_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}\,dz^\alpha\wedge d\bar{z}^\beta\right)(X,Y) = g_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}\left( dz^\alpha(X)d\bar{z}^\beta(Y) - dz^\alpha(Y)d\bar{z}^\beta(X)\right)
\end{align*} 
is clearly antisymmetric in $(X,Y)$. To see the indices of $J$ explicitly, compute:
\begin{align*}
 J_{i\bar{j}} = J(\partial_i,\partial_{\bar{j}})
= g_{k\bar{\ell}}(\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}-\delta_{i\ell}\delta_{jk}),
\end{align*}
where $\delta$ denotes the Kronecker delta. Now it's again explicit that $J_{i\bar{j}}=-J_{j\bar{i}}$.

Just to note, your $J$ is usually called the Kahler form and denoted $\omega$. People usually reserve $J$ for the (almost-) complex structure.